# Issue with Kendo MVVM Cascading drop down

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown, kendo-mvvm

I am working on developing a cascading drop down with Kendo MVVM. The issue is that when the drop down loads the child drop down initially displays "undefined". This disappears though when I select some data in the parent drop down.

Alternatively I also require a Reset button in place. On click of this button I need to reset the cascade so that we get back to the initial phase(i.e. the child drop down should be disabled and no data should be selected in the parent).

Please find a JSBin that I created for the issue [here](http://jsbin.com/mibenuxupo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using IDs as values, not strings. I think you can play around with `data-primitive-value` but why? Just use proper structure to begin with. For the clear, just `dropdownlist.select(0)` or `dropdownlist.select("")` if you managed to make it work with the primitive value thing.

http://dojo.telerik.com/ePIDO